# IntelliJ Idea navigate class and search everywhere not pop up

Tags: intellij-idea

When I try to use the navigate class (cmd + o), navigate file (shift + cmd + o) or search everywhere (double shift) function in Idea, there's no window popup.

I've tried to open the window both from the menu and by shortcut, but neither works.
[from menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjYr5.png)

The Idea version is 2021.3.

Anyone knows the possible reason?

Comment: Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and install the latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download. If the problem remains contact IntelliJ support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect logs and diagnostic Data)

Comment: It works after I disabled all third-party plugins, thanks.